# Lua - Attempt to index local 'item' (a function value)

Tags: lua

I'm getting this error, and I can't figure out if it's a scoping issue, a logic issue, or something else entirely.  The objective, in C terms, is to modify a pointer within a module to change the behavior of the draw() command.  The place the error is coming from is:

```
function M.draw()
  for k, item in pairs(M.buttons.current) do
    love.graphics.setColor(M.buttons.bkg_color)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", item.pos_x, item.pos_y, M.buttons.size_x, M.buttons.size_y)
    love.graphics.setColor(M.buttons.txt_color)
    --TODO: center text on button
    love.graphics.print(item.text, item.pos_x+10, item.pos_y+10)
  end
end
```

This function works in the first menu, but when I click a button to change menus, the error pops up in the love.graphics.rectangle(...) line.  The code that changes M.buttons.current is:

```
function M.mousereleased(x, y, button)
  if button == 'l' and M.buttons.buttonPressedFlag and M.mouseCollide(x,y,M.buttons.buttonPressed) then
    M.buttons.buttonPressed.fun()
  end
  M.buttons.buttonPressedFlag = false
end
```

and the button I'm clicking is defined during initialization using:

```
M.formButton( M.buttons.main,
              "options",
              GLOBAL_SETTINGS.resolution_x/2-M.buttons.size_x,
              GLOBAL_SETTINGS.resolution_y/7*5-M.buttons.size_y,
              M.buttons.size_x,
              M.buttons.size_y,
              "Options",
              function() M.buttons.current = M.buttons.main.options end )
```

where M.formButton is defined at the top of the module:

```
function M.formButton(menu, buttonName, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y, text, fun)
  menu[buttonName].pos_x = pos_x
  menu[buttonName].pos_y = pos_y
  menu[buttonName].size_x = size_x
  menu[buttonName].size_y = size_y
  menu[buttonName].text = text
  menu[buttonName].fun = fun
end
```

Each of the buttons that should be in the new menu is defined similarly.
For reference, the prototype of the module's structure is:

```
local M = {buttons = { main = { campaign =    { newgame =  {},
                                                continue = {},
                                                load =     {},
                                                back =     {} },
                                freeplay =    { newgame =  {},
                                                continue = {},
                                                load =     {},
                                                custom =   {},
                                                back =     {} },
                                multiplayer = { lan =      { newgame = {},
                                                             load =    {},
                                                             back =    {}, },
                                                hotseat =  { newgame = {},
                                                             load =    {},
                                                             back =    {}, },
                                                network =  { newgame = {}, 
                                                             load =    {},
                                                             back =    {} } },
                                options =    {  audio =    {},
                                                display =  {},
                                                gameplay = {},
                                                language = {} },
                                exitgame =   {} } } }
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is coming from the the third line in the mouseReleased function combined with the way I've instantiated the button, but I can't figure out what the issue is.  It's probably something distressingly simple that I'm missing because I'm fairly new to the language, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As the error message states, you're accessing a field in the variable `item`, but it contains a function. Print out the contents of `M.buttons.current` and make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: Before I click the button, M.buttons.current contains table 0x41...10, and after I click the button, it contains table 0x41...98, so the table is changing.  If I print out the items in each table, then the first table contains a set of tables, and the second table contains a function (probably the function to change M.buttons.current), but I don't see how the function got in there.

Comment: Ok, I see.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably overriding `M.buttons.options` or `M.buttons.current` somewhere, changing it to a function value. Try adding `print(type(M.buttons.current), type(M.buttons.options))` periodically between function calls - you should be able to narrow it down to the offending code.

Comment: shouldn't it be `type` instead of `typeof`?